# erase-remove idiom with smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dereference

I need to be able to remove elements from a vector and decided to look into the erase-remove idiom, an algorithm from the C++ Standard Library preferable to use than a hand-written loop. I also wanted to use a vector of smart pointers, rather than raw pointers.

I found lots of posts about the erase-remove idiom, quite of them advising in fact the use of smart pointers. Following this advice, I wrote 3 workable examples of the erase-remove idiom that I copy here below preceded by the output: with no pointers, raw pointers and smart pointers. Notice the triple dereference needed for smart pointers.

My question: is this a good implementation of the erase-remove idiom with smart pointers or is there some... smarter way? Thank you for caring.

> vector of int:  1 1 3
>   vector of int:  3
>   vector of pointers of int:  1 1 3
>   vector of pointers of int:  1 3
>   vector of smart pointers of int:  1 1 3
>   vector of smart pointers of int:  1 3

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

std::vector<int> intVector;
std::vector<int*> intVectorPointers;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int*>> intVectorSmartPointers;

void printVector(std::vector<int> intV){
    std::cout << "vector of int: ";
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = intV.begin(); it != intV.end(); it++)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void printVectorPointers(std::vector<int*> intVPointers){
    std::cout << "vector of pointers of int: ";
    for (std::vector<int*>::const_iterator it = intVPointers.begin(); it != intVPointers.end(); it++)
    std::cout << ' ' << **it;
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void printVectorSmartPointers(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int*>> intVSmartPointers) {
    std::cout << "vector of smart pointers of int: ";
    for (std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int*>>::const_iterator it = intVSmartPointers.begin(); it != intVSmartPointers.end(); it++)
    std::cout << ' ' << ***it;
    std::cout << '\n';
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int int1 = 1;
    int int2 = 1;
    int int3 = 3;

    int *intPointer1 = &int1;
    int *intPointer2 = &int2;
    int *intPointer3 = &int3;

    std::shared_ptr<int*> intSmartPointer1 = std::make_shared<int*>(intPointer1);
    std::shared_ptr<int*> intSmartPointer2 = std::make_shared<int*>(intPointer2);
    std::shared_ptr<int*> intSmartPointer3 = std::make_shared<int*>(intPointer3);

    intVector.push_back(int1);
    intVector.push_back(int2);
    intVector.push_back(int3);

    intVectorPointers.push_back(intPointer1);
    intVectorPointers.push_back(intPointer2);
    intVectorPointers.push_back(intPointer3);

    intVectorSmartPointers.push_back(intSmartPointer1);
    intVectorSmartPointers.push_back(intSmartPointer2);
    intVectorSmartPointers.push_back(intSmartPointer3);

    printVector(intVector);
    intVector.erase(std::remove(intVector.begin(), intVector.end(), int1), intVector.end());
    printVector(intVector);

    printVectorPointers(intVectorPointers);
    intVectorPointers.erase(std::remove(intVectorPointers.begin(), intVectorPointers.end(), intPointer1), intVectorPointers.end());
    printVectorPointers(intVectorPointers);

    printVectorSmartPointers(intVectorSmartPointers);
    intVectorSmartPointers.erase(std::remove(intVectorSmartPointers.begin(), intVectorSmartPointers.end(), intSmartPointer1), intVectorSmartPointers.end());
    printVectorSmartPointers(intVectorSmartPointers);;

    Sleep(50000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're asking to improve working code you're probably better off asking at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<int*>`? Why?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<int*>` is a smart pointer *equivalent* to `int**`...

Comment: and for-range would remove the dereference of `iterator`.

Comment: Before using dynamic allocation first make sure you need it. Then wrap it with a unique_ptr until you are forced to weaken ownership. shared_ptr should be in the last resort category.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ Did not know, thank you. @juanchopanza Need pointers, so I can implement polymorphism. They are pointers on objects, not ints - ints are just for the example. And, sure, unique_ptr should always be considered first.

Comment: You don't need smart pointers of pointers!

Comment: @juanchopanza Smart point on... smart pointers! This will remove a level of redirection. The simplification needed, upvoted. Was fun coding the triple indirection, though! Thank you, all. ;-)))

Comment: @LastBlow: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fe2b8a3a370f423 notice: only one layer of indirection in any one place

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, there are problems with the code other than the delete itself.

However, the reason why the `std::remove_if()` fails is because you search for intPointer1 and remove just one one pointer, and not pointers that point to the number 1.

You do not say whether you have access to C++11 or better hopefully you do. You can write a lambda to do that:

```
intVectorPointers.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        intVectorPointers.begin(),
        intVectorPointers.end(),
        [](auto const & p) { return *p == 1; }),
    intVectorPointers.end());
```

I haven't tested with your entire code, but something like that should work. (This is assuming you fix your pointer and *p actually points to the data and not another pointer as in your example, which I am pretty sure is not what you want.)

Comment: I see your point, thank you, I also realized that while toying with the example. Yes, an erase-remove idiom erases all elements having the same value, like it does for the vector of ints. Only, I do not need to remove all such elements but only a particular one pointed to by a given smart pointer what for I am trying to use the erase-remove idiom, so I can avoid the vector iterator invalidation.

Comment: Note that `*p` is an `int*`.

Comment: @LastBlow, ah. In that case, you could just use the `erase(iterator)`. Because whether you do that or `erase(remove(...))`, the iterator becomes invalid. If you do not want to lose the pointer, all you need is another reference in another place such as another vector that has all the pointers.

Comment: @juanchopanza, yes, hence my comment about that fact that there are other problems.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the use of `unique_ptr` implies the availability of C++ (unless it's the partial support from g++ 4.x with `-std=c++0x`).

Comment: @TobySpeight, ah, it's true he has an `std::shared_ptr<>()`, so obviously, at least C++11 or close enough.

Answer (score -1):

So it could help others, here below a cleaned-up version of the erase-remove idiom with smart pointers. In regard to your comments, no more pointers of pointers, unique pointers rather than shared pointers and `remove_if()` instead of `remove()`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

void printVectorSmartPointers(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> &vSmartPointers) {
    std::cout << "vector of smart pointers of int: ";
    for (std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>::const_iterator it = vSmartPointers.begin(); it != vSmartPointers.end(); it++)
    std::cout << ' ' << **it;
    std::cout << '\n';
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::unique_ptr<int> smartPointer1 = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    std::unique_ptr<int> smartPointer2 = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    std::unique_ptr<int> smartPointer3 = std::make_unique<int>(3);

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vectorSmartPointers;

    vectorSmartPointers.push_back(std::move(smartPointer1));
    vectorSmartPointers.push_back(std::move(smartPointer2));
    vectorSmartPointers.push_back(std::move(smartPointer3));

    printVectorSmartPointers(vectorSmartPointers);

    vectorSmartPointers.erase(
        std::remove_if(
        vectorSmartPointers.begin(),
        vectorSmartPointers.end(),
        [](std::unique_ptr<int> const &p) { return *p == 1; }),
        vectorSmartPointers.end());

    printVectorSmartPointers(vectorSmartPointers);

    Sleep(50000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AlexisWilke Just published a cleaned-up version of the erase-remove idiom with unique pointers, here above. Thank you for your code snippet from 2 days ago! Please, let me know if there are any other problems.